# Scrape URLS with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I've scraped the HTML code of the following table. I would like to scrape just the link associated to each element of the table, how can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print tds
```

The result is like this:

```
[<td><a href="./A/013/0.html">ENFERMERÍA</a></td>]
[<td><a href="./A/0141/0.html">TEC. MED. LAB. CLÍNICO Y ANATOMÍA PATOLÓGICA</a></td>]
[<td><a href="./A/0142/0.html">TEC. MED. TERAPIA FÍSICA Y REHABILITACIÓN</a></td>]
[<td><a href="./A/0143/0.html">TEC. MED. RADIOLOGÍA</a></td>]
```

Comment: That output doesn't look like a python output of an array? Have you copied it correctly?

Comment: Also, I rarely use beautifulSoup, but given what you have, why not just use `links = td.find_all('a')` to get the links in the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output all links, provided that there are just one link in each `td`.

```
for td in tds:
    print td.a['href']
```

But it's probably easier to just use `find_all` on the `tr` element:

```
for link in tr.find_all('a'):
    print link['href']
```

If you want to save them in a list, just do this instead:

```
links = []
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    links.extend([link['href'] for link in tr.find_all('a')])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one table in the page, so you can simply use a list comprehension

```
links = [row.a['href'] for row in soup.find_all('tr') ]
```

Result

```
['./A/011/0.html', './A/012/0.html', './A/013/0.html', './A/0141/0.html', './A/0142/0.html', './A/0143/0.html', './A/0144/0.html', './A/015/0.html', './A/041/0.html', './A/042/0.html', './A/043/0.html', './A/051/0.html', './A/071/0.html', './A/072/0.html', './A/073/0.html', './A/081/0.html', './A/101/0.html', './A/102/0.html', './A/103/0.html', './A/131/0.html', './A/132/0.html', './A/141/0.html', './A/142/0.html', './A/144/0.html', './A/145/0.html', './A/162/0.html', './A/163/0.html', './A/165/0.html', './A/166/0.html', './A/167/0.html', './A/171/0.html', './A/172/0.html', './A/181/0.html', './A/191/0.html', './A/192/0.html', './A/193/0.html', './A/201/0.html', './A/202/0.html']
```